# SQL How to correctly set a date variable value and use it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2008

I have the following query which uses a date variable, which is generated inside the stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @sp_Date DATETIME
SET @sp_Date = DateAdd(m, -6, GETDATE())

SELECT DISTINCT pat.PublicationID
     FROM PubAdvTransData AS pat 
     INNER JOIN PubAdvertiser AS pa ON pat.AdvTransID = pa.AdvTransID
     WHERE (pat.LastAdDate > @sp_Date) AND (pa.AdvertiserID = 12345))
```

The problem is that the @sp_Date value appears to be being ignored and I am wondering why?  Have I defined or used it incorrectly?

Comment: How do you know that it's being ignored?  Do you see rows in the output where `LastAdDate` is earlier than 6 days ago?

Comment: What do you mean by ignored? Is not filtering or what?

Comment: It is pulling in data which is from longer than 6 months ago.  Francisco Soto, yes, not filtering on date.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your syntax is fine, it will return rows where `LastAdDate` lies within the last 6 months;

```
select cast('01-jan-1970' as datetime) as LastAdDate into #PubAdvTransData 
    union select GETDATE()
    union select NULL
    union select '01-feb-2010'

DECLARE @sp_Date DATETIME = DateAdd(m, -6, GETDATE())

SELECT * FROM #PubAdvTransData pat
     WHERE (pat.LastAdDate > @sp_Date)

>2010-02-01 00:00:00.000
>2010-04-29 21:12:29.920
```

Are you sure `LastAdDate` is of type `DATETIME`?

Comment: Actually you were right, it wasn't DATETIME is was smalldatetime and I have resolved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you manually write out the query with static date values (e.g. '2009-10-29 13:13:07.440') do you get any rows?

So, you are saying that the following two queries produce correct results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pat.PublicationID
FROM PubAdvTransData AS pat 
    INNER JOIN PubAdvertiser AS pa 
        ON pat.AdvTransID = pa.AdvTransID
WHERE (pat.LastAdDate > '2009-10-29 13:13:07.440') AND (pa.AdvertiserID = 12345))

DECLARE @sp_Date DATETIME
SET @sp_Date = '2009-10-29 13:13:07.440'

SELECT DISTINCT pat.PublicationID
FROM PubAdvTransData AS pat 
    INNER JOIN PubAdvertiser AS pa 
        ON pat.AdvTransID = pa.AdvTransID
WHERE (pat.LastAdDate > @sp_Date) AND (pa.AdvertiserID = 12345))
```

Comment: If I write the query out manually the date aspect works fine, but if I set it dynamically in the stored procedure I get a larger dataset, the date being ignored for some reason...

Comment: @flavour404 - So, if you try the two queries I added to my post, they work correctly?