# Creating a date variable to use in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, date, declare

Hi I would really appreciate some help. I would like to declare 2 variables as dates in the date format as `date1 = 31-AUG-15` and `date2 = 01-SEP-15` and use that within the `SELECT` statement so I don't need to keep typing in dates everywhere  when I need to change the date. Is this possible?

```
SELECT TABLE1.TRANSACTION_ID, TABLE1.AMOUNT, TABLE1.MATURITY, TABLE1.TYPE,
TABLE1.EFFECTIVE_DATE, TABLE1.SETTLEMENT_DATE, TABLE2.TRANSACTION_DATE 
FROM TABLE1 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.TRANSACTION_ID = TABLE2.TRANSACTION_ID AND TABLE2.TRANSACTION_DATE = date2
WHERE TABLE1.MATURITY > date1
AND TABLE1.EFFECTIVE_DATE > date1
AND TABLE1.SETTLEMENT_DATE = date1
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: You can use a .sql file to contain both the variable declaration and the sql to help reduce repetition, but I am not aware of anything that would let you  define a variable, may be you can use the DUAL table on Oracle.

Comment: I'm just using toad to pull data from an oracle sql database table. I would really appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what type of SQL you are using (MSSQL, MySQL, Oracle SQL, ...).
I can help you with a snippet for Microsoft SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @date1  DATETIME,
        @date2  DATETIME

SET @date1 := '08-31-15'
SET @date2 := '09-01-15'

SELECT TABLE1.TRANSACTION_ID, TABLE1.AMOUNT, TABLE1.MATURITY,
       TABLE1.TYPE, TABLE1.EFFECTIVE_DATE, TABLE1.SETTLEMENT_DATE, TABLE2.TRANSACTION_DATE 
FROM TABLE1 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.TRANSACTION_ID = TABLE2.TRANSACTION_ID AND TABLE2.TRANSACTION_DATE = date2
WHERE TABLE1.MATURITY > date1
      AND TABLE1.EFFECTIVE_DATE > date1
      AND TABLE1.SETTLEMENT_DATE = date1
```

I hope this helps.
I used answers to this question: [SQL How to correctly set a date variable value and use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740420/sql-how-to-correctly-set-a-date-variable-value-and-use-it)
as a reference.

Comment: Thanks Elvar. The table is in Oracle SQL and I am using toad to query. However, I am getting an error encountered the symbol date2 when expecting following :=,(@%; not null range default character

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/overview.htm#BABEABGF), you should use a `DECLARE` statement.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039907/simple-oracle-variable-sql-assignment) will provide more details on dates in particular:

```
DECLARE 
    date1 DATE := to_date('03/11/2011', 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```